# Webdav share (SharePoint) modification date gets updated when selecting/clicking a file

Tags: sharepoint, webdav

In a SharePoint document library there is a option to open the library as webdav share with Windows Explorer.

When I am browsing the webdav share and I select a file (not opening it or anything, just single click), the modifcation date gets updated.

I stopped all services on the client machine, to avoid the file being indexed or virus scanned, but it still happens.

What could cause this?